# Inout Text field generates a blank line when converted to string and output

Tags: javascript, string, actionscript-3, text, input

Okay, so.  I am making a text based game and I require a name input field.  I looked at a lot of ways to do it, but couldn't understand most of them, or they were such workarounds that I couldn't justify making such messy code.  This is what I have for my current script.

```
function handler(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(event.charCode == 13)
    {
        Input.toString()
        myText = Input.text
        trace(myText)
    }
}
```

Sorry I don't know how to make those fancy blocks I see all over this site. =S

All I need it to do is take the input text from a field and assign a string to that text when the enter key is pressed.

Okay.  The code works.  However, since Enter is the key I press to submit the inout, it adds a second blank line.  And everytime I type something new, it adds it to the string.

I.E.  Say I go and type my name as "Will"  And then press enter.  It outputs:
\rWill
\r

If I type something new, like "Bill" it outputs:
Will
Bill
\r
\r

And the blank just gets bigger because it keeps creating new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the conditional:

```
function handler(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(event.charCode == 13)
    {
        if (event.preventDefault)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        Input.toString()
        myText = Input.text
        trace(myText)
    }
}
```

This will verify browser support and cancel whatever would happen when pressing Enter otherwise.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I don't really know where you want me to put that.  I got an error when I tried to put that at the beginning of the function, but before my own if conditions

Comment: 3553: Function value used where type Boolean was expected.  Possibly the parentheses () are missing after this function reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekxi/KXyLZ/

```
 /*check out the two keydown event handler function in the fiddle */
```

Type in text. Press enter. Your input goes into a String. Type text. Don't press enter. You have your old text. Press enter again. New text will be there in your String.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant to tag this in ActionScript 3 category.  The java script relation I don't really understand, as I am in no way versed in java.

Comment: Oh, nevermind! May be this helps when you are using JavaScript :) ..and I would now go and search about ActionScript. :)